# activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3 while running ruby 2

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have Ruby v2 installed:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin11.0]
```

but I get this error on multiple gems when I run:

```
$ sudo gem update
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

### EDIT 1:

```
$ gem update
Updating installed gems
Updating actionmailer
Fetching: activesupport-4.1.8.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

### EDIT 2:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
- GEM PATHS:
    - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
    - /Users/user/.gem/ruby/1.8
    - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

$ rvm info
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

Comment: The Ruby that root is using is not the same Ruby as your user account is using. If you're running RVM you should not install gems with `sudo`.

Comment: $ sudo su
sh-3.2# ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin11.0]

Not running RVM

Comment: Add the output of `gem env`, `rvm info` and `echo $PATH` to your question, by editing it, pasting in their output, and formatting it for readability. It sounds like you're using RVM or rbenv, and violating the basic tenet of *NEVER* using `sudo` to install gems when using a sandbox. `sudo` escalates your privileges to root's, and root doesn't know anything about your sandboxes, so it puts the files into Apple's system Ruby installation, which you don't want to mess with unless you understand when and why to do so.

Comment: aw didn't know about gem env. running this reveals RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7. How do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

The gem env was using an old version of ruby. I completely removed the gems via

```
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | sudo xargs gem uninstall -aIx
```

(keep this terminal tab open so you know which gems you had and you can reinstall them) then opened a new terminal tab and then removed gem by doing

```
$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
$ cd /usr/bin && sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/gem gem1.8.7 && sudo rm gem
```

I symlinked gem to gem1.8.7 if I want to use it later on.

Then I followed directions here https://rubygems.org/pages/download to reinstall gem with the latest ruby version, in my case Ruby 2.1.2p95.